# Requests and error 101 network is unreachable

Tags: python, python-requests

i've ran a python bot on raspberry with raspbian for over a month without any problem.
Now, since some days, i'm facing this error, and i'm pretty sure i didn't touch anything in bot code and raspberry system.

```
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/cugino/wrapper.py", line 92, in sendMessage
'reply_to_message_id':reply_to_message_id
File "/home/pi/Desktop/cugino/wrapper.py", line 55, in post
r = requests.post("%s/bot%s/%s" % (self.api_url,self.token,method),params,files=files,timeout=60)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, 
in request
response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", 
line 465, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", 
line 573, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", 
line 
415, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))
```

The code that trigger the error is

```
        r = requests.post("%s/bot%s/%s" % (self.api_url,self.token,method),params,files=files,timeout=60)
```

all was working, then suddently this error pops out.
The real strange thing is that this error occours occasionally, the bot run fine, it works, but it have alot of delay when this error occour, then it start to work normally, erro 101, and so on.
I use no proxy, no ipv6. Browser, internet and another bot runs fine without problems.

Comment: What is `self.api_url` value?

Comment: api_url = "https://api.telegram.org"

Comment: Are you sure you (still) have a Internet connection? Did you check that the site is still online?

Comment: That's a dead link for me. Can you get what you expect in a browser?

Comment: I found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73138/rpi2-python-requests-fails-for-https-errno-101) on raspberry stackexchange. Maybe something there helps?

Comment: @MegaIng yessir, i always check it when the error occours, and yes, i already checked your linked question :((  ^roganjosh on my last comment it's a dead link, on wrapper.py is https://api.telegram.org and yes, it's reachable.

Comment: actually, i resolved the problem by implementing telepot (he manage this error without problems) instead of manual api connection to telegram, that's why my other bot runs normal (it use telepot) but this still a mistery..

Comment: Did you forget protocol part? http:// or https://?

Comment: no sir. @AmaroVita otherwise it will give error everytime i tried to launch it.

Comment: Well, did you forget `/` in your format string then? Should it be `"%s/bot/%s/%s"`?

Comment: no i didn't, Telegram require token just after "bot".